# Table: Color, alignment, and linebreak in cells

Tags: tables, line-breaking, code, colortbl

**Code**

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  landscape
]{article}

\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[
  a3paper,
  margin = 0.77cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\mlr{2.5}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\raisebox{\fpeval{#1*\mlr}ex}{\textbf{#2}}}}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{\fpeval{-5/9*\mlr}ex}{#1}}
\newcommand*\tid[2]{\saenk{#1\,--\,#2}}
\definecolor{dansk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{matematik}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{historie}{rgb}{1.0, 0.55, 0.0}
\definecolor{engelsk}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.8}
\definecolor{tysk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{biologi}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{geografi}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{fysik}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{idraet}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{mad}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}
\newcommand*\laerer[2]{
  \cellcolor{#2}
  {\ifstrequal{#2}{dansk}
    {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
    {\ifstrequal{#2}{matematik}
      {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
      {\ifstrequal{#2}{tysk}
        {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
        {\ifstrequal{#2}{engelsk}
          {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
          {\ifstrequal{#2}{mad}
            {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
            {\textcolor{black}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}}}}}}
\newcommand*\lokale[2]{
  \cellcolor{#2}
  {\ifstrequal{#2}{dansk}
    {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}
    {\ifstrequal{#2}{matematik}
      {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}
      {\ifstrequal{#2}{tysk}
        {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}
        {\ifstrequal{#2}{engelsk}
          {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}
          {\ifstrequal{#2}{mad}
            {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}
            {\textcolor{black}{\saenk{#1}}}}}}}}}
\newcommand*\fag[2]{%
  \cellcolor{#2}%
  {\ifstrequal{#2}{dansk}
    {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
    {\ifstrequal{#2}{matematik}
      {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
      {\ifstrequal{#2}{tysk}
        {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
        {\ifstrequal{#2}{engelsk}
          {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
          {\ifstrequal{#2}{mad}
            {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}
            {\textcolor{black}{\saenk{#1}}}}}}}}}
\newcommand*\nyLinje[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\LARGE
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{
        |>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{6.51cm}
   *{5}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.67cm}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{2.08cm}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.67cm}}|
 }
  \hline
  {\bfseries\backslashbox{Tidsrum}{Ugedag}}
   & \mc{-0.3}{Mandag}
   & \mc{-0.3}{Tirsdag}
   & \mc{-0.3}{Onsdag}
   & \mc{-0.3}{Torsdag}
   & \mc{-0.3}{Fredag}  \\
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{8:10}{8:55}
   & \laerer{SA}{engelsk}   & \fag{ENG}{engelsk}   & \lokale{C-14}{engelsk}
   & \laerer{MA}{geografi}  & \fag{GEO}{geografi}  & \lokale{C-14}{geografi}
   & \laerer{KS}{dansk}     & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{C-14}{dansk}
   & \laerer{JO}{idraet}    & \fag{IDR}{idraet}    & \lokale{Gym}{idraet}
   & \laerer{MØ}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{C-14}{matematik} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{8:55}{9:40}
   & \laerer{ME}{tysk}      & \fag{TYS}{tysk}      & \lokale{C-14}{tysk}
   & \laerer{MA}{geografi}  & \fag{GEO}{geografi}  & \lokale{C-14}{geografi}
   & \laerer{KS}{dansk}     & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{C-14}{dansk}
   & \laerer{JO}{idraet}    & \fag{IDR}{idraet}    & \lokale{Gym}{idraet}
   & \laerer{MØ}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{C-14}{matematik} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{9:40}{10:00}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{10:00}{10:45}
   & \laerer{NP}{biologi}   & \fag{BIO}{biologi}   & \lokale{C-35}{biologi}
   & \laerer{SA}{engelsk}   & \fag{ENG}{engelsk}   & \lokale{C-14}{engelsk}
   & \laerer{MØ}{fysik}     & \fag{F/K}{fysik}     & \lokale{C-29}{fysik}
   & \laerer{MØ}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{C-14}{matematik}
   & \laerer{\nyLinje{KS\\[-0.5ex]RK}}{dansk}
   & \fag{\nyLinje{DAN\\[-0.5ex](STJ)}}{dansk}
   & \lokale{C-14}{dansk} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{10:45}{11:30}
   & \laerer{NP}{biologi}   & \fag{BIO}{biologi}   & \lokale{C-35}{biologi}
   & \laerer{JO}{historie}  & \fag{HIS}{historie}  & \lokale{C-14}{historie}
   & \laerer{\nyLinje{MØ\\[-0.5ex]JJ}}{fysik}
   & \fag{\nyLinje{F/K\\[-0.5ex](STJ)}}{fysik}
   & \lokale{C-29}{fysik}
   & \laerer{\nyLinje{MØ\\[-0.5ex]MA}}{matematik}
   & \fag{\nyLinje{MAT\\[-0.5ex](STJ)}}{matematik}
   & \lokale{C-14}{matematik}
   & \laerer{KS}{dansk}     & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{C-14}{dansk} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{11:30}{12:15}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{12:15}{13:00}
   & \laerer{MØ}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{C-14}{matematik}
   & \laerer{ME}{tysk}      & \fag{TYS}{tysk}      & \lokale{C-14}{tysk}
   & \laerer{SA}{engelsk}   & \fag{ENG}{engelsk}   & \lokale{C-14}{engelsk}
   & \laerer{KS}{dansk}     & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{C-14}{dansk}
   & \laerer{ME}{tysk}      & \fag{TYS}{tysk}      & \lokale{C-14}{tysk} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{13:05}{13:45}
   & \laerer{\nyLinje{KS\\[-0.5ex]NP}}{dansk}
   & \fag{\nyLinje{DAN\\[-0.5ex](STJ)}}{dansk}
   & \lokale{C-14}{dansk}
   &                        &                      & 
   & \laerer{NB}{mad}       & \fag{MAD}{mad}       & \lokale{B-82}{mad}
   & \laerer{\nyLinje{KS\\[-0.5ex]RK}}{dansk}
   & \fag{\nyLinje{DAN\\[-0.5ex](STJ)}}{dansk}
   & \lokale{C-14}{dansk}
   &                        &                      &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{13:45}{13:5}
   &                        &                      & 
   &                        &                      & 
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   & \mc{0}{\saenk{Pause}}
   &                        &                      &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{13:55}{14:40}
   &                        &                      & 
   &                        &                      & 
   & \laerer{NB}{mad}       & \fag{MAD}{mad}       & \lokale{B-82}{mad}
   & \laerer{JO}{historie}  & \fag{HIS}{historie}  & \lokale{C-14}{historie}
   &                        &                      &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: before]

**Question**

Now each cell looks something like

[image: before]

What I would like to achieve is

[image: after]

with two lines of text in each cell, where the top one is centered (and with a larger font size) and the bottom one is flushed left and right, respectively. (**Update**: The (three combined) cells with text on top of one another is not important; I can rewrite that to get it all on a single line.)

Also, the code is very cumbersome (in my opinion), so I would also like to improve on it, if possible.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages independently from each other. To maximize the packages' mutual compatibility, do run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint. I'll (try to) remember that in future.

Comment: @Mico a new version of colortbl has been uploaded which now contains all the xcolor fixes. So this is no longer needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Great news indeed!

Comment: @JasperHabicht The code complies just fine for me.

Comment: @JasperHabicht \fpeval is now in the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package which makes it easier to cope with cell color, line breaks, alignment etc.

I simplified your approach that checks against the background color of the cell in order to decide whether the font should be white or black. I defined a comma list via [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) that takes all darker colors and that is checked against the background color of the cell. If the background color of the cell is in that list, the text of the cell will be printed white.

I also enhanced the macro you use to print the time. It checks whether there is only one or more characters in front of the colon of the first argument. If there is only one, it adds a horizontal space of the width of a digit in order to make everything aligned nicely in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper, margin=0.77cm, landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\definecolor{dansk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{matematik}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{historie}{rgb}{1.0, 0.55, 0.0}
\definecolor{engelsk}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.8}
\definecolor{tysk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{biologi}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{geografi}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{fysik}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{idraet}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{mad}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}

\forcsvlist{\listadd\darkcolors}{dansk, matematik, tysk, engelsk, mad}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\tid{ m m }{%
    \tl_set:Nn \l__temp_tl { #1 }%
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { :\d+ } { } \l__temp_tl%
    \if_int_compare:w \str_count:N \l__temp_tl = 1%
        \hphantom{0}%
    \fi:%
    #1\,--\,#2%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewTableCommand\laerer[1]{
    \SetCell{font=\large,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\NewTableCommand\fag[1]{
    \SetCell{font=\Huge,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\NewTableCommand\lokale[1]{
    \SetCell{font=\large,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\begin{document}

\LARGE
\begin{center}
 \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {
             Q[l,m,6.51cm] 
        *{5}{Q[c,f,1.67cm]
             Q[c,h,2.08cm]
             Q[c,f,1.67cm]}
        },
        hlines,
        vline{1,2,5,8,11,14,17} = {1-Z}{solid},
        rows = {1.75cm, abovesep=10pt, belowsep=5pt},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    } 
    
  \SetCell{c,m} \diagbox{Tidsrum}{Ugedag}
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m} Mandag  & & 
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m} Tirsdag & & 
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m} Onsdag  & & 
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m} Torsdag & &
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m} Fredag  & & \\
     \tid{8:10}{8:55}
   & \laerer{engelsk}   SA           & \fag{engelsk}   ENG             & \lokale{engelsk}   C-14
   & \laerer{geografi}  MA           & \fag{geografi}  GEO             & \lokale{geografi}  C-14
   & \laerer{dansk}     KS           & \fag{dansk}     DAN             & \lokale{dansk}     C-14
   & \laerer{idraet}    JO           & \fag{idraet}    IDR             & \lokale{idraet}    Gym
   & \laerer{matematik} MØ           & \fag{matematik} MAT             & \lokale{matematik} C-14 \\
     \tid{8:55}{9:40}
   & \laerer{tysk}      ME           & \fag{tysk}      TYS             & \lokale{tysk}      C-14
   & \laerer{geografi}  MA           & \fag{geografi}  GEO             & \lokale{geografi}  C-14
   & \laerer{dansk}     KS           & \fag{dansk}     DAN             & \lokale{dansk}     C-14
   & \laerer{idraet}    JO           & \fag{idraet}    IDR             & \lokale{idraet}    Gym
   & \laerer{matematik} MØ           & \fag{matematik} MAT             & \lokale{matematik} C-14 \\
     \tid{9:40}{10:00}
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,font=\bfseries} Pause & &
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,font=\bfseries} Pause & &
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,font=\bfseries} Pause & &
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,font=\bfseries} Pause & &
   & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,font=\bfseries} Pause & & \\
     \tid{10:00}{10:45}
   & \laerer{biologi}   NP           & \fag{biologi}   BIO             & \lokale{biologi}   C-35
   & \laerer{engelsk}   SA           & \fag{engelsk}   ENG             & \lokale{engelsk}   C-14
   & \laerer{fysik}     MØ           & \fag{fysik}     F/K             & \lokale{fysik}     C-29
   & \laerer{matematik} MØ           & \fag{matematik} MAT             & \lokale{matematik} C-14
   & \laerer{dansk}     { KS \\ RK } & \fag{dansk}    { DAN \\ (STJ) } & \lokale{dansk}     C-14 \\
 \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you rather would like to have things arranged in two lines, you would need to rearrange everything. Sadly, nesting is not a good idea when using `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper, margin=0.77cm, landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\definecolor{dansk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{matematik}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{historie}{rgb}{1.0, 0.55, 0.0}
\definecolor{engelsk}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.8}
\definecolor{tysk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{biologi}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{geografi}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{fysik}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{idraet}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{mad}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}

\forcsvlist{\listadd\darkcolors}{dansk, matematik, tysk, engelsk, mad}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\tid{ m m }{%
    \tl_set:Nn \l__temp_tl { #1 }%
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { :\d+ } { } \l__temp_tl%
    \if_int_compare:w \str_count:N \l__temp_tl = 1%
        \hphantom{0}%
    \fi:%
    #1\,--\,#2%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewTableCommand\fag[1]{
    \SetCell[c=2]{font=\Huge,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\NewTableCommand\laerer[1]{
    \SetCell{font=\large,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\NewTableCommand\lokale[1]{
    \SetCell{font=\large,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\begin{document}

\LARGE
\begin{center}
 \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {
              Q[l,m,6.5cm] 
        *{10}{Q[c,f,1.75cm]}
        },
        hline{1,2,4,6,8,10,12} = {1-Z}{solid},
        vline{1,2,4,6,8,10,12} = {1-Z}{solid},
        rows = {1cm, abovesep=10pt, belowsep=5pt},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    } 

  \SetCell{c,m} \diagbox{Tidsrum}{Ugedag}
   & \SetCell[c=2]{c,m} Mandag  & 
   & \SetCell[c=2]{c,m} Tirsdag & 
   & \SetCell[c=2]{c,m} Onsdag  & 
   & \SetCell[c=2]{c,m} Torsdag &
   & \SetCell[c=2]{c,m} Fredag  & \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{m} \tid{8:10}{8:55}
   & \fag{engelsk}   ENG             & 
   & \fag{geografi}  GEO             & 
   & \fag{dansk}     DAN             &
   & \fag{idraet}    IDR             &
   & \fag{matematik} MAT             & \\
   & \laerer{engelsk}   SA           & \lokale{engelsk}   C-14
   & \laerer{geografi}  MA           & \lokale{geografi}  C-14
   & \laerer{dansk}     KS           &  \lokale{dansk}    C-14
   & \laerer{idraet}    JO           & \lokale{idraet}    Gym
   & \laerer{matematik} MØ           & \lokale{matematik} C-14 \\
 \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, in this case, the easiest would probably be not to use sub-divided cells and just to use a line break and `\hfill` to arrange the three small text parts inside the cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper, margin=0.77cm, landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\definecolor{dansk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{matematik}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{historie}{rgb}{1.0, 0.55, 0.0}
\definecolor{engelsk}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.8}
\definecolor{tysk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{biologi}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{geografi}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{fysik}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{idraet}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{mad}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}

\forcsvlist{\listadd\darkcolors}{dansk, matematik, tysk, engelsk, mad}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\tid{ m m }{%
    \tl_set:Nn \l__temp_tl { #1 }%
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { :\d+ } { } \l__temp_tl%
    \if_int_compare:w \str_count:N \l__temp_tl = 1%
        \hphantom{0}%
    \fi:%
    #1\,--\,#2%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewTableCommand\fag[1]{
    \SetCell{font=\Huge,bg=#1}
    \ifinlist{#1}{\darkcolors}{
        \SetCell{fg=white}
    }{}
}

\begin{document}

\LARGE
\begin{center}
 \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {
             Q[l,m,6.5cm] 
        *{5}{Q[c,m,5cm,rightsep=10pt,leftsep=10pt]}
        },
        hlines,
        vlines,
        rows = {1cm, abovesep=10pt, belowsep=5pt},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    } 

  \SetCell{c,m} \diagbox{Tidsrum}{Ugedag}
   & Mandag  
   & Tirsdag  
   & Onsdag   
   & Torsdag 
   & Fredag  \\
  \SetCell{m} \tid{8:10}{8:55}
   & \fag{engelsk}   { ENG \\ { \large SA \hfill C-14 } } 
   & \fag{geografi}  { GEO \\ { \large MA \hfill C-14 } }  
   & \fag{dansk}     { DAN \\ { \large KS \hfill C-14 } }  
   & \fag{idraet}    { IDR \\ { \large JO \hfill Gym  } }  
   & \fag{matematik} { MAT \\ { \large MØ \hfill C-14 } } \\
 \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: I am unsure why the `\diagbox` does not align nicely, so I just centered it in the cell.

Comment: This looks very good! There is a small issue, however: I would like the text at the top of each cell block (for example "ENG" in the first one) to span the two (not three) below ("SA" and "C-14" in the first one). This is because I want some longer names at the top. (Sorry for not showing that in my original drawing!)

Comment: Well then, you would need to split the rows of course.

Comment: I tried that in a former test file without success. I would much appreciate it, if you would show me how to do it. (Thank you in advance.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Actually, I think that you should probably not divide the cells that much and just use a line break and `\hfill` to arrange the three text parts in the colored cells.

Comment: One other thing: Assume I want to change the veritcal spacing in each cell to, say, `abovesep = 10pt` and `belowsep = 5pt`. Then the numbers in the first column are no longer centered; how can I do that?